# Transpiled TypeScript enums don't get type hints in VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a TS project that I'm transpiling for use as a nodejs module. I've got that part working. In said project, I have some enums that I want accessible internally and externally. When I install the package in another project, I can access the enums and their values, but VS Code can't autocomplete the enum properties, or show me any of the JSDocs on it. The only other exported value does have autocomplete and JSDocs. What am I doing wrong?

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2022",
      "module": "NodeNext",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declarationMap": true,
      "isolatedModules": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
  }
```

package.json:

```json
[...]
  "main": "./dist/TaxCalculator/VaporTaxCalculator.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/TaxCalculator/VaporTaxCalculator.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/TaxCalculator/VaporTaxCalculator.js"
    },
    "./enums/ProductCategory": {
      "types": "./dist/TaxCalculator/enums/ProductCategory.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/TaxCalculator/enums/ProductCategory.js"
    },
    "./enums/TaxAppliesTo": {
      "types": "./dist/TaxCalculator/enums/TaxAppliesTo.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/TaxCalculator/enums/TaxAppliesTo.js"
    }
  },
[...]
```

Over in my test project, where I've run `npm install ../vapor-tax-calculator`, I've got a basic JS file with the contents:

```js
import { TaxAppliesTo } from "vapor-tax-calculator/enums/TaxAppliesTo";

console.log(TaxAppliesTo);
```

I can see the values in the output, but VS Code doesn't suggest any values when I add a `.` after `TaxAppliesTo`. Similarly, I get none of my JSDocs when I hover over the value.

Comment: [mre] please. include source content and emitted type declaration.